# How do I attach a webform to another webform's submission?

Tags: webforms

I found a demo for the Webform module which includes 2 forms: *application* and *application evaluation*. Once the *application* form is submitted, the *application evaluation* is attached at the bottom of the page showing the submitted data for the *application* form.

I tried to do the same with two webforms I created: *PO* and *PO Approval*. I want to attach the *PO Approval* webform to the submission of the *PO* webform.

I did the the follow setup(Structure->Block layout).

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Then I tested it.

> [image: screenshot]

Differently from the demo, the webform was not attached the webform submission page of the other webform.

How do I attach a webform to another webform's submission?

**UPDATE:**
I found if I do "flush plugins cache" then it will show up at bottom of the submission. I tested every single "flush", only "flush plugins cache" works.

here is the pic before "flush plugins cache"

[image]

here is the pic after "flush plugins cache"

[image]

As far as I know, after "flush", the submission page became "content" and before "flush" it was not "content"(Webform UI ?).

It is still not exactly same as the demo does. Hopefully this update can give more information to someone who can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You say you `could not attach the webform to another webform's submission like the demo did`. What exactly went wrong? Why exactly didn't it work?

Comment: Please look at the demo, When you check the results->Submission of webform "Application", at the bottom, you will find the webform "Application Evaluation" . I want create such a couple webform to do the same thing. But I want to know how to do it. Please let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much kiamlaluno!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually find what the problem is. There are two solutions can solve this issue:
1) change the default administrative theme to default theme
[image]

2) Follow the demo to make a block YAML file like this:
  /my_module/config/optional/block.block.seven_webform_demo_application_evaluation.yml

Hope this can help someone else has the same issue.